# Nginx config for setting Wordpress as home page but /listing pages from node

Tags: node.js, wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx

(I dont have much knowledge setting up any nginx config)

#### Hi, I want to setup my aws nginx configuration as

i want to open

```
www.example.com or  
www.example.com/contact or  
www.example.com/about  
as my Wordpress Pages
```

but I have my node/ejs pages as well.

#### My node API's are like /categories, /countries

So if i want to go for

```
www.example.com/list/categories
```

it should open my pages served by node

#### This is my configuration (in nginx/sites-available/default) for serving my wordpress pages-

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
         client_max_body_size 100M;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
             include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

#### it works fine and shows my wordpress site when i hit the IP but

#### now i am adding new server block (for serving node pages) below this wordpress server block in default so it look like now as:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
         client_max_body_size 100M;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
             include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        
        location /list {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

#### I am able to open the wordpress as my home page or example.com/about etc..

#### but when I open example.com/list/categories or any other node api, i get badgateway 502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Here is the nginx configuration that worked for me.

```
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ ^/(something|somethingelse|javascripts|stylesheets|images) {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add your folders (which exists in public folder) in this configuration as I did.

Answer (score 0):

As of you are opening `example.com/list/categories`, then your config should look like:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
         client_max_body_size 100M;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
             include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location /list {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way, where i dont need to add /list in example.com/list/categories, and i just use it as example.com/categories??? that would be really very great coz this solution is not working for me